# how to get span value with .post in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, .post

I am using .post jquery in order to delete data from my mysql table. But I don't know how to get the text between span. In my example, when I click apple picture, it will delete apple picture, but I need a value to use $_POST in my delete.php, I know how to get value from input and textarea. but I don't know how to do that when it is span or div. I use .text(), but it doesn't work. Any way? Appreciate.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".tag img", function() {
  $.post("delete.inc.php", {

      tag: $("#result_tag0").text(),

    },
    function(data) {

    });

  $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

```html
<span class="result_tag" id="result_tag0"><img src="pic">apple</span>
<span class="result_tag" id="result_tag1"><img src="pic">berry</span>
<span class="result_tag" id="result_tag2"><img src="pic">banana</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a DOM traversal function to find the `<span>` containing the image that was clicked.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".tag img", function() {
  $.post("delete.inc.php", {

      tag: $(this).closest("span").text(),

    },
    function(data) {

    });

  $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

```html
<span class="result_tag" id="result_tag0"><img src="pic">apple</span>
<span class="result_tag" id="result_tag1"><img src="pic">berry</span>
<span class="result_tag" id="result_tag2"><img src="pic">banana</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery:

```
$("#result_tag0").text()
```

is not doing what you want because the span has no text in it (just an image).

What you want depends on how you are going to identify the image to be deleted. Two possibilities:

```
$('#result_tag0').attr('id')
```

if you want to use the span ID, or

```
$('#result_tag0 img').attr('src')
```

if you want to use the value of the image src.